# Fail to assign the global variable with Swift and Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

As a Swift beginner, I'm building an App in Swift.

In TestOC2Swft.swift I create a global variable called macStr:

```
var macStr:String?
```

And I have a function(Func 1) to assign value to it:

```
func changeWindVol(inputStr:NSString){
    macStr=inputStr as String
}
```

And I also have another function(Func 2) to get this string,something like:

```
@IBAction func TestBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    print(macStr! as String)
}
```

the String inputStr is from a 3rd-party objective-C file:

```
TestOC2Swft *testSw = [[TestOC2Swft alloc]init];
[testSw changeWindVolWithInputStr:dev.mac];
```

Then I run the debug module:

Before Func 1, macStr is nil.

After Func 1:
[after func 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isAI2.png)

We can see that macStr is assigned correctly.
How ever, in Func 2:
[capture at func 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxucK.png).

The value of macStr becomes nil again!

Finally some long-long error message will appear:

```
    libswiftCore.dylib`function signature specialization <preserving fragile attribute, Arg[2] = Dead, Arg[3] = Dead> of Swift._fatalErrorMessage (Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, file : Swift.StaticString, line : Swift.UInt, flags : Swift.UInt32) -> Swift.Never:
    ...
    Swift.StaticString, line : Swift.UInt, flags : Swift.UInt32) -> Swift.Never).(closure #2)
    ...
    0x100400444 <+116>: bl     0x1002e14dc               ; function signature specialization <preserving fragile attribute, Arg[1] = [Closure Propagated : reabstraction thunk helper from @callee_owned (@unowned Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer<Swift.UInt8>) -> () to @callee_owned (@unowned Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer<Swift.UInt8>) -> (@out ()), Argument Types : [@callee_owned (@unowned Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer<Swift.UInt8>) -> ()]> of generic specialization <preserving fragile attribute, ()> of Swift.StaticString.withUTF8Buffer <A> ((Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer<Swift.UInt8>) -> A) -> A
    ->  0x100400448 <+120>: brk    #0x1
```

I totally can't understand this error message.

What's wrong with my poor app? How can I change my global variable macStr?

Comment: You'll see that MacBtn is nil in the other case. My guess? You are not using the same object.

Comment: @Larme : do you mean when I write "TestOC2Swft *testSw = [[TestOC2Swft alloc]init];" in OC file, I create another TestOC2Swft.swift object so the macStr refer to different objects?  How can I share the same value in all TestOC2Swft.swift class objects?

Comment: @boweitsai : TestBtn is a IBAction. Place where u set macStr you simply instantiate new instance of TestOC2Swft and neither present it modally or push it to navigation stack. So obviously when u tap on a button u tapping on different instance of TestOC2Swft and set the macStr of different instance of TestOC2Swft hence nil

Comment: @SandeepBhandari :Thank u. I find what's wrong with me... Can I share one value with all instances of TestOC2Swft objects? how can I accomplish  that?

Comment: @boweitsai : create a static variable that will be available to access to all objects not just all objects of TestOC2Swft  but to every single objects in app. Not sure whats your requirement is but what u have asked for this works

Answer (score 1):

I think you would benefit from a Singleton pattern here. In a separate Swift file:

```
class GlobalVariables {
  static var macStr: String?
}
```

Then in Function 1:

```
func changeWindVol(inputStr:NSString){
  GlobalVariables.macStr = inputStr as String
}
```

In Function 2:

```
@IBAction func TestBtn(_ sender: Any) {
  guard let macStr = GlobalVariables.macStr else { return }
  print(macStr)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I solve this question by Simply:

**Put the definition of the variable outside the class.**

Here is the code:

```
var macStr:String?
class TestOC2Swft {
...
}
```

Then the variable "macStr" will share by all files. There will be only one "macStr" in my project.

The other way to solve the problem is provided by @PranavKasetti .